# Wget in powershell with stdout

Tags: powershell, stdout, wget

Everyone, I'm in the process of writing a powershell script to ingest the logs to our cloud SIEM, my scrip shown as below,

```
$Username = 'username'
$Password = 'password'
$Url = "https://10.x.x.x/spi/NAHERETDGBF/etc/log/auditlog"
$Path = "C:\Praba\auditlog" 
$WebClient = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($Username, $Password)
$WebClient.DownloadFile( $Url, $Path )
```

But my SIEM application vendor does not support the logs to be stored in the directory, the downloaded log output should be a stdout, please find their below response for your information,

SIEM Support Response: **The Collector executes the script as the user running the Collector process. Your script needs to output the data to your machine's stdout or stderror output streams to be collected.**

Can someone help me on it ? can the wget help me ? if so, please share the command line

Thanks,
Praba

Comment: `$WebClient.DownloadFile( $Url, $Path )` -> `$WebClient.DownloadString($Url)`

Comment: What is relation of wget with this question. Wget.exe is linux utility which functions like curl to get web source code (and obviously used to download files). Here your question is about System.Net.WebClient to get web content. So why are wanting wget help?

Comment: I was just asking if my goal can be achieved by wget or curl